# Unable to login the application when using IIS Express Development Certificate in SSL

Tags: c#, iis, ssl, https

I have implemented SSL connection in my application. For this I have added IIS Express Development Certificate while hosting the site in IIS.

I could use other pages with SSL. ie., https://localhost/general

I am unable to login the application using SSL. My url changing like https://localhost/accounts/login and becomes empty page.

I am getting the below error in Firefox browser.
This site makes use of a SHA-1 Certificate; it's recommended you use certificates with signature algorithms that use hash functions stronger than SHA-1.

I have tried by using Self-signed certificate also.

Is this problem arise because of IIS Express Development Certificate ??

Answer (score 1):

Either you use full IIS or IIS Express, the default self-signed certificates generated are SHA-1 only, and now become obsolete.

To generate SHA-2 certificates, you can use Jexus Manager,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/03/jexus-manager-enhanced-self-signed-certificate-generation/